# Mathematical maps for encryption

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, chaos-theory

I am doing a short term project on image encryption.using chaotic maps.
I just want some ideas and hints of such maps other than the chaotic baker map ,arnold map ,standard map etc..that have the desired properties of ergodicity and random like behaviour.Even maps that are not chaotic but can be used in image encryption in some way either for shuffling or diffusion of the pixels can be suggested.
The basic idea is to propose a novel idea for enctyption.
Just yesterday i saw a map called Cantor pairing function and noted it down just because i thought it would be useful for the fact that it is invertible.I know this might be totally silly but still i would want to use it somewhere..Just like i can use Chinese remainder theorem for image enctyption which i read in a reserach paper..
Guys if you can just suggest something it would be of great help.
Just to add i dont need any abstract algebra field theory ideas

Thnx in advance.

Comment: yes but is there something else

Comment: @Upstart Dont know much but how about applying Logistic equation in some sense? or any function which contains exponential terms as that could create enormous change in small change of input values too ?

Comment: yup man that has been applied with parameter value greater that$3.57.$.thanx for the suggestion

Comment: how about Cantors function ?  a self repeating structure ?

Comment: Thnx man i'll try to use this.